# Restore purchases in auto renewable app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

In my Cocoa app, there is only auto-renewing subscription.

I check all the purchases when app starts and load the data only for purchased items.

I am also checking if there is any change(especially discontinuing the subscription) in the purchases every hour.(i.e I am not serializing user subscription in NSUserDefaults for security. They are always loaded from server when app starts)

Is it still necessary to put a `Restore Purchases` button in app ?
IMHO Restore button does not make any sense in app where you have only  auto-renewing subscription.

Also is there any notification from apple when auto-renewable subscription ends ? Or what is the right way to check if the auto-renewing subscription has ended. Presently I am polling every hour for latest valid subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You must need to provide a Restore Purchases option or functionality unless it will be reject by apple reviewer.

If you delete the app and again try to install this app then how to validate this user already having valid subscription.

Please check below what apple document says -

[image]

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf

Comment: I check all the purchases when app starts and load the data only for purchased items. Please read the entire question

Comment: Ok . If you are maintain purchase items state in your server then you don't need to provide Restore Button explicitly.